# How to port POSIX system calls fork() and wait() to Visual Studio 2010 express?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, fork, posix, wait

Is there anyway possible to port or imitate UNIX/POSIX system calls, ie. fork() and wait(), to Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition? I've tried integrating SUA with Visual Studio, however, it the installation due to incompatibility with my processor. :(

Any help will be well appreciated.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23kc048(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Alright thanks. I'll check it out

Comment: Which option would you use personally?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how closely you wish to imitate wait and fork.

If fork is just used to create another process and you are not worried about inheriting handles, semaphores etc, then try CreateProcess.  There isn't anything in Windows that inherits setups from its parent.

One of the parameters for CreateProcess is process information.  The equivalent for wait is WaitForSingleObject with the first parameter as the handle of the process (from process information) and the second parameter as INFINITE.

Both these function calls are in the windows.h header.

Comment: Write a C program using the fork() system call that generates this sequence in the child process.  The starting number will be provided from the command line.  For example, if 8 is passed as a parameter on the command line, the child process will output 8, 4, 2, 1.  Because the parent and child processes have their own copies of the data, it will be necessary for the child to output the sequence.  Have the parent invoke the wait() call to wait for the child process to complete before exiting the program.

Comment: ...Perform necessary error checking to ensure that a positive integer is passed on the command line.

Comment: The program is listed in the 2 comments after cup's post.

Comment: If it says use fork, then they are probably expecting you to use a Mac or a Linux system.  If you have a Windows PC, install either VMWare player, Hypervisor or VirtualBox then install a Linux VM on it - then you can just use gcc or g++.

Comment: My teacher said that I could imitate it. So do you think CreateProcess and WaitForSingleObject would be effective for this assignment?

Comment: Yes - all you need to do is pass in the command line argument to the child process.  It is not using any inheritance mechanism.